# SSIS script task doesnt populating data for SSAS tabular model properties

Tags: ssis, ssas

I am using ssis script task to get ssas property information like database name, database id, last processed date,last schema update and status .we have migrated from 2012 to 2016 server after that my package is running fine but it is populating only database name to destination table rest is null ,due to this i am facing lot of issues and for multi dimensional cubes data are fine ..only issue with tabular model...
Please help me... appreciate your help..

Comment: Hi can you please include more information? schemas and queries are always useful.

Comment: Hi , I do not use any queries to load data , i do use C# code to populate  SSAS model Properties to destination table . similar to the link : https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5385/retrieve-ssas-properties-using-analysis-services-management-objects-and-ssis/

Answer (score 0):

The link you have referenced is for the Multi-dimension model. For Tabular Model, you need to use the: [Tabular Object Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tom/introduction-to-the-tabular-object-model-tom-in-analysis-services-amo?view=asallproducts-allversions)

This means that your C# script task has to change.
The following is an outline code for getting details of a Tabular Model:

```
private static void GetCubeDetails()
    {
        //Server
        var server = new Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Server();
        server.Connect(CubeConnectionStringDest);

        LogUtil.Log(server.LastSchemaUpdate.ToString());

        //Database
        var db = server.Databases.FindByName(DatabaseNameDest);
        LogUtil.Log(db.LastProcessed.ToString());

        //Model
        var model = db.Model;
        
        //table
        foreach(var table in model.Tables)
        {
            LogUtil.Log(table.ModifiedTime.ToString());

            //partitions
            foreach(var partition in table.Partitions)
            {
                LogUtil.Log(partition.State.ToString());
                LogUtil.Log(partition.RefreshedTime.ToString());
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: I have added 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.dll' and made some code changes , now it worked as expected . Thank you for your help.